# React native: How to display the posts for a specific category?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I currently have a screen that has a horizontal ScrollView at the top with about 5 tabs inside and each tab is a category. Underneath my scrollView i am rendering a flatlist for the posts of that specific category selected from my tabs.

My problem is i cannot get the posts to appear when i selected a tab. Something is missing in my code and its been days and i still dont know whats wrong.

I have tested on postman to make sure my url is working and it is, i am getting a response.

```
URL: http://LOCALHOST/categories/1?page=0
```

here 1 is my 1st category "sports".

```
RESPONSE:

{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test",
    "subTitle": "test",
    "userId": 43,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "User": {
        "id": 43,
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "Category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sports"
    },
}
]
```

Here is my code:

```
function tabScreen({ navigation,route }) {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const loadPosts = async (id) => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await getCategoryPostsAPI(id) //API call
setLoading(false);

if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
setError(false);
  setPosts(response.data)
};

useEffect(() => {
loadPosts();
}, []);

// in my backend my categories are stored with same name and id
const categories = [
{
  label: "Sports",
  id: 1,
},
{
  label: "Fashion",
  id: 2,
},
{
  label: "News",
  id: 3,
},
{
  label: "Cooking",
  id: 4,
},
{
  label: "Education",
  id: 5,
}]

const[label,setLabel]=useState('Sports')

const setLabelFilter=label=>{
setLabel(label)
}

const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState()

const toggleBrands = (categoryId) => {
setCurrentCategoryId(categoryId)
setLabel(label)
};

return (

<ScrollView 
    horizontal 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
    {categories.map(e=>(
            <TouchableOpacity 
                key={e.id}
                onPress={()=>{toggleBrands(e.id),setLabelFilter(e.label)}}
                selected={e.id === currentCategoryId}
                >
            <Text>{e.label}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
    </ScrollView>

<FlatList
      data={currentCategoryId ? posts.filter(post=>post.categoryId===currentCategoryId
        ):posts.filter(post=>post.categoryId===1)} 
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
       <Card
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subTitle}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.POST_DETAILS, {post:item,index})}
        />
      )}
    />
```

Finally, here is my api call code:

```
const getCategoryPostsAPI = (id)=>client.get(`/categories/${id}`)
```

I think my problem is in not passing the category id correctly or not even passing it. It would be of great help if anyone can help me out. And if any explanation is required, please go ahead and tell me.

Also, when i do console.log(posts) i keep getting Array[]

**Update**

```
const loadPosts = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await getCategoryPostsAPI(5) //API call
setLoading(false);

if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
setError(false);
setPosts(response.data)
};
```

in my API call, when i specify the id as 5 and go to the 5th tab the posts appear, how can i change this value depending on which tab i have selected?

Comment: Does **currentCategoryId** change when you press some tab?

Comment: yes it does, console.log(currentCategoryId) returns 1 when i press on sports etc..

Comment: So, try to filter your posts inside **setLabelFilter** function and update the state with your new array.

Comment: @J.Doe my problem is when i try console.log(posts) i keep getting Array[ ] instead of getting the actually posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i managed to solve this problem. Here is the solution that worked with me. If anyone has any better solution please tell me.

So my problem was that i could not set the category tab to get the posts for each category, after many attempts i found that i was not setting the id of my api call to my category tab id dynamically.

```
const loadPosts = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await getCategoryPostsAPI(id) //API call
setLoading(false);

if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
setError(false);
setPosts(response.data)
};

useEffect(() => {

loadPosts(1);

// since when page loads the default tab is category 1, we need to set 
loadPosts to category 1, so as soon as the page loads an api is sent 
to get the posts of category 1.//

}, []);

<TouchableOpacity 
            key={e.id}
            onPress={()=>{loadPosts(id=e.id}}
            >
```

If anyone has any questions please go ahead and ask.